# Custom Media Types Used In Request's Body Content Type When Designing A REST Service?

Tags: http, rest, hateoas, hypermedia

When creating your own custom media type format (say application/vnd.myapp+xml), should the client when sending body content, do so in the custom media type?

For example you PUT a representation of an order to a uri.  Should the content be application/vnd.myapp+xml, or just xml, since the client is not going to be including hypermedia controls like links?

The server will always respond with the custom media type if the user accepts it (which it should), but do clients have to use it in their request bodies?

Comment: Put another way -  When a client agrees to our domain application protocol, it is understood that will be using a custom domain specific hypermedia as means of communication, and thus should be the passed back and forth between client and server.

Answer (score 3):

Clients don't necessarily have to send data to the server (e.g. via PUT or POST) using the same media type that the server sends back in a GET response.  It's up to the service to decide what media types it can receive and what types it will return.  And of course, it can be implemented so as to support multiple media types in both directions for the same resource.

Comment: i thought part of the reason of using a custom media type (HATEOAS) in a rest service is to represent a contract between the two.

Comment: Well, it's true that a custom media type (as opposed to something generic like "application/json") defines the syntax and semantics of a representation, and that is part of the contract between the client and the server.  And a server can decide it will only consume representations of the same media type(s) that it produces.  But it may choose to be more flexible, e.g. allowing browsers to POST web forms as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", but supporting custom media types (e.g. "application/vnd.mycompany.foo+json" "application/vnd.mycompany.foo+xml") from JSON- or XML-centric clients.

Comment: Yup.  Makes sense, and is what I thought should be the case.  Would like to hear a few more voices on the topic.

Comment: By the way, regarding your point about HATEOAS, a given client may be led via link relations to URIs of resources it may want to PUT/POST to, and those link relations may indicate a custom media type to use.  But different clients (browsers, javascript-centric clients, or XML-centric clients) might receive different link relations with different media types best suited to them.  And since REST is stateless, a server doesn't know or care whether a client's PUT/POST follows a link relation previously sent, and thus doesn't know or care whether the supplied media type is consistent with it.

Comment: Right, but if the client accepts our hypermedia we would probably put the mediaType attribute in our links for that client set to our hypermedia.  So in that case the client would PUT/POST with content-type=application/vnd.mycompany+json

Comment: Yes, they likely would, but they wouldn't be "breaking the contract" (IMHO) if they PUT/POST using another acceptable media type.  HATEOAS leads the client in a useful direction and reduces coupling, but personally I don't see it as a contract (i.e. a link relation with a specified media type doesn't dictate that the client _MUST_ use the indicated media type -- unless it's the only one supported, of course).  But I'm open to other viewpoints, also.

Answer (score 2):

> When creating your own custom media type format (say
>   application/vnd.myapp+xml), should the client when sending body
>   content, do so in the custom media type?

No, take for example HTML. HTML is different media type though data can be submitted in text/plain, application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data. All these supported types are defined by HTML spec itself and can be provided inside form definition. So it's up to you how you coordinate client with this control factor(i.e. enctype in HTML.FORM)

For example there are two JSON formats which have write semantics:

Collection+JSON: http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/format/

Which explicitly defines the data submit format and is a application/vnd.collection+json

Collection.next+JSON: http://code.ge/media-types/collection-next-json/

Supports same as above and additionally has support of "enctype" attribute and service implementor can specify desired media type for data submissions.

> The server will always respond with the custom media type if the user
>   accepts it (which it should), but do clients have to use it in their
>   request bodies?

See answers above.